# How to write JUnit test cases for if else conditions in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have written an if else condition  to create a brand in my spring boot controller class. How can I write the JUnit test cases for these conditions?Below shown is my controller class with the method for saving a new brand.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/brand/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseDTO createBrand(@RequestBody Brand brand) {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
        Random rand = new Random();
        try {
            List<String> brandNames = brandService.findAllBrandNames();
            System.out.println(brandNames.toString());
            if (brandNames.contains(brand.getName())) {
                responseDTO.setCode(ErrorCode.error_1100);
                responseDTO.setMessage(ErrorCode.error_msg1100);

            } else {
                brand.setBrandId("HSB" + rand.nextLong());
                String brandId = valid.generateBrandId(brand.getBrandId());
                if (brandId.contains("-")) {
                    brandId = brandId.replace("-", "").trim();
                }
                brand.setBrandId(brandId);
                brand.setActive(true);
                brand.setDeleted(false);
                brand.setCreatedOn(new Date(cal.getTime().getTime()));
                brand.setCreatedBy("vendor");
                brand.setModifiedOn(new Date(cal.getTime().getTime()));
                brand.setModifiedBy("vendor");
                brandService.save(brand);
                responseDTO.setCode(ErrorCode.error_0);
                responseDTO.setMessage("Created brand successfully.");
                responseDTO.setData(brandId);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseDTO.setCode(ErrorCode.error_1101);
            responseDTO.setMessage(ErrorCode.error_msg1101);
            return responseDTO;
        }
        return responseDTO;

    }
```

Comment: Can you use spring's `MockMvc`?

Comment: yes.. But how could I write the test cases?

Comment: Write business logic (if-else part) in the service layer, then follow this https://dzone.com/articles/junit-testing-spring-mvc-0 for junit test cases.

Comment: Couldn't I test the coditions in the controller? @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5341306/imran-khan

Comment: putting the logic in your `Controller` is an anti-pattern by the way

Comment: How to write test cases for the catch block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
@MockBean
private BrandService brandService;

...
// if you want to test brandNames.contains(brand.getName())
Mockito.when(brandService.findAllBrandNames())
      .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("brand name"))
// now just send brand.setName("brand name"),it should test what's inside if block
```

twick it to test the else block

Comment: How to write test cases for the catch block?